# React render element is invalid while the import and export seem alright

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Export and import of `App` seem alright. The error must be due to some mixing of names. This is my first react application. I have scoured various StackOverflow posts with the same error but I couldn't extract helpful insight from them. So, please be a bit elaborate.

**Error**:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `App`.

Index.js :

```
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(<App /> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.jsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import { StreamChat } from 'stream-chat';
import { Chat } from 'stream-chat-react';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
    
import { ChannelListContainer, ChannelContainer } from './components';
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="app__wrapper">
            <Chat client={client} theme="team light">
                <ChannelListContainer 
                
                />
                <ChannelContainer

                />
            </Chat>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

index.js in ./components:

```
export { default as ChannelContainer } from './ChannelContainer';
export { default as ChannelListContainer } from './ChannelListContainer';
```

Comment: Can you share the imports at the top of `App.jsx`?

Comment: Check `Chat` and `ChannelContainer`

Comment: Can you share the code for `Chat` and `ChatContainer`, the fault is not in the code you provided.

Comment: ChannelListContainer and ChannelContainer are being imported from an intermediarry file index.js in components folder.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you're using:

```
export { default as ChannelContainer } from "./ChannelContainer";
export { default as ChannelListContainer } from "./ChannelListContainer";
```

You need to export `ChannelContainer` from `./ChannelContainer` like:

```
const ChannelListContainer = () => {
  return <>ChannelListContainer</>;
};
export default ChannelListContainer;
```

And export `ChannelListContainer` from `./ChannelListContainer` like:

```
const ChannelContainer = () => {
  return <>ChannelContainer</>;
};
export default ChannelContainer;
```

Here's the sample based on your structure:

[image: Edit loving-night-w6r5e]

Comment: Is this syntax `return <>ChannelListContainer</>` correct?

Comment: @AlanOmar Sure. This is a alternative for `Fragment` in react: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Comment: I know but it is rendered as text node check the codebox you attached

Comment: @AlanOmar I know that. This is just a sample to show OP what's the problem, because OP haven't shared the code of  components.

Comment: I proceeded further with the implementation of my project and the error just went away. No changes were made in the elements relevant to this error.